# ember-cli remove/limit console logging

Tags: ember-cli

I'm sure this is a familiar sight to the ember-cli crowd:
[image]

I can't find how to configure this logging functionality in ember-cli so I don't have to scroll for days, then pick out, values I have personally logged out in my app.  I want to know how to turn off or limit this default behavior.
Using ember-cli v0.0.39

Comment: In `config/environment.js` under `development environment` you have by  default some of the configs that enable certain logging. You can enable/disable those there. Hope that helps

Comment: That worked great! I would add that you need to restart the ember server for any edits you make in config/environment.js to take effect.  If you post an answer, you got some points!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `config/environment.js` under `development environment` you have by default some of the configs that enable certain logging. You can enable/disable those there. 
And also make sure to restart `ember server` so the changes take effect.